# Docbook: How to create an article with parts

Tags: docbook, docbook-5

I need to create a "Terms of Use" document that consists of three parts... and I've tried to create an article like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE article [
  ...
]>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook http://docbook.org/xml/5.0/xsd/docbook.xsd"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xml:lang="en-US"
  xml:id="terms-of-use">
<info>
  <title>Terms of Use</title>
  <copyright>
    <year>2015</year>
    <holder>My Company, Inc.</holder>
  </copyright>
  <legalnotice>blah blah blah</legalnotice>
  <date>October 16, 2015</date>
  <releaseinfo>1.0</releaseinfo>
</info>
<part label="I">
  <title>Title Part One</title>
  <xi:include href="part-1/file-1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="part-1/file-1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="part-1/file-N.xml"/>
</part>
<part label="II">
  <title>Title Part Two</title>
  <xi:include href="part-2/file-1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="part-2/file-1.xml"/>
  <xi:include href="part-2/file-N.xml"/>
</part>
</article>
```

The document above doesn't work because I guess it doesn't comply with the schema... Is there any helpful example that shows how to create an article with parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t actually create a DocBook `article` that contains a `part` element. In DocBook, [a `part` is a division in a `book`](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/part.html). I think what you want here instead is just [the `section` element](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/section.html).

You can of course title your sections as **Part One**, etc., and conceptually just think of them as “parts”—but in DocBook, the thing that’s actually given the special name `part` is a thing that’s restricted to modeling just the parts of a book, and `section` is a thing for modeling the parts (and sub-parts, recursively) of an article or of a chapter in a book.